# Dynamic Addition of Option Menu tKinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I'm quite new to python. I have a requirement where I have to read a data file and based on the number of records inside the file, I have to create the same number of option menus related to that data. But option menu's options can be fetched from simple list. Please find the code below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("GridAssign")


Grids=('Grid1','Grid2','Grid3','Grid4','Grid5')
file=open(Datafilepath,"r")
ing=file.read().splitlines()
print (len(ing))

variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set(Grids[0])

for i in range(len(ing)):

  label = tk.Label(root,text=ing[i])
  label.grid(row=i,pady=3,sticky=W)
  w=OptionMenu (root, variable, *tuple(Grids)))
  w.grid(row=i,column=2,pady=3,sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

The above code is able to give me n number of option menus but if I choose one value in one option menu other option menu's value also changes. Can someone please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks,
Santty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because each of your `OptionMenu` are using the same `StringVar`.  So naturally when one OptionMenu makes a change to that StringVar, the other menus also reflect that change.

To prevent this you can use a separate StringVar for each menu:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("GridAssign")


Grids=('Grid1','Grid2','Grid3','Grid4','Grid5')
file=open(Datafilepath,"r")
ing=file.read().splitlines()
print (len(ing))

variable_dict = {}

for i in range(len(ing)):
    variable = StringVar(root)
    variable.set(Grids[0])
    variable_dict[i] = variable

    label = tk.Label(root,text=ing[i])
    label.grid(row=i,pady=3,sticky=W)
    w=OptionMenu (root, variable, *tuple(Grids)))
    w.grid(row=i,column=2,pady=3,sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

You can then access each of the StringVars through the dictionary `variable_dict`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response.Will try it out.